# Add a new album to Facebook, along with an update/description

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

Does anyone know the correct way to create a new album, add photos and post, all at the same time and have a status update that describes this album? It can be done with several photos added as a non-album, but when you add new album, the description appears on each photo and not on the news feed. Hence you get just an album added with no information. Seems a bit odd.

I have iOS and a Mac.

Comment: If I understand your question correct then, At the album creation time you can add a description about the album and description about each photo. It will appear in news feed as 'Barry added 2 photo to the album_name - album_description'. When someone click on any photo of that album user can see the particular description of that photo.